# Left joining count(*) from second table

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm trying to return fields from a single row of table one (posts) and join to this row the number of comments appearing in a second table (comments) for that post.

However, it never returns the count value.

```
SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_author, posts.post_date, posts.post_article
FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.comment_post_id = 25) AS comments
ON posts.post_id = comments.comment_post_id WHERE post_id = 25;
```

I know I'm probably missing something simple, but have spent far too much time on this already, so thought I'd ask for help. As I'm new to SQL, I would really appreciate an explanation as well as any code change suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.post_author, p.post_date, p.post_article,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM comments c
        WHERE c.comment_post_id = p.post_id
       ) as num_comments
FROM posts p
WHERE p.post_id = 25;
```

This efficiently allows you to have the `25` only once in the query -- reducing the scope for coding errors.

Your code doesn't work because you are not selecting the count column in the outer `SELECT`.  Remember:  A SQL query describes the result set.  If you don't have a column or expression in the `SELECT`, it is not going to be selected.

Comment: Concise and works like a charm!

Thanks, also, for the explanation - I've been reading up on the order in which statements are processed, as a result of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not need an outer join since the count si query will have exactly one row. Assuming you want to do that, then include post_id in your subquery.

```
SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_author, posts.post_date, posts.post_article, ncomments
FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) as ncomments FROM comments WHERE comments.comment_post_id = 25) AS comments
ON posts.post_id = comments.comment_post_id WHERE post_id = 25;
```

Otherwise, I think this should do:

However, it never returns the count value.

```
SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_author, posts.post_date, posts.post_article, ncomments
FROM posts INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ncomments FROM comments WHERE comments.comment_post_id = 25) AS comments
```

Answer (score 0):

two way for this Problem..

one way and fast solution..

```
SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_author, posts.post_date, posts.post_article,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.comment_post_id = posts.comment_post_id)CountComment
FROM posts post
WHERE post_id = 25;
```

and best solution..

```
select mainQueryPosts.post_title, mainQueryPosts.post_author, mainQueryPosts.post_date, mainQueryPosts.post_article,mainQueryPosts.count,mainQueryPosts.rownumber
from (
SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_author, posts.post_date, posts.post_article,count(*) over (partition by comments.comment_post_id) count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by comments.comment_post_id ORDER BY comments.CreateDate) rownumber
FROM posts  inner join comments  on comments.comment_post_id = post.comment_post_id
WHERE post_id = 25
) mainQueryPosts
where mainQueryPosts.rownumber=1
```

Nader Gharibian Fard